# Python increment value in function call

Tags: python, multithreading

So I've been exploring threading, and I was wondering if there's a analog to ++ in python like c. Essentially, I want to call a thread and as the thread is called, increment a value. So an analogue of `thread.start_new_thread(function, (variable++,))`

I looked for other questions, and I kinda doubt this is possible, but any help is appreciated.

The specific code I'm playing with is this:

```
import thread

def isprime(x):
global list
for i in range(3, x-1,2):
    if x % i == 0:
        return
print x
list.append(x)


n = 1000000
i=3
list = [2]
while i < n:
    try:
        thread.start_new_thread(isprime,(i,))
        i+= 2
    except:
        pass

print sorted(list)

print len(list)
```

Comment: please dont use `list` as a variable name, as it is an inbuilt type

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd want to use `++` here anyway, since that would only increment `i` by 1, so all it would help you do is to replace `i += 2` with `i += 1`.

Comment: @user2246087 Yeah, sorry I use it when I am making really short programs and not using the function. It's bad practice and I should change.

Comment: @abarnert I want +=2, I was just using ++ because I know it's possible in C.

Comment: But `i++` doesn't add 2, and `i++++` isn't legal in C (`i++` isn't an lvalue, so you can't `++` it), so… again, either you need to do `i++` and then `i += 1`, or two `i++` statements. Either way, you're making your code harder to read, and possibly slower, and not saving any keystrokes, so… why?

Comment: @abarnert Because I felt like the += was being applied at the wrong time, and I wanted to check to see if I could increment in the call, and I know that ++ doesn't work, but I wanted to see if there was a solution I was ignoring.

Comment: Just for the record, Python doesn't even have mutable integers. That said, your code has a race condition, you need to use a mutex around shared data structures.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python has no equivalent of `++`, and that's intentional. It's a philosophical difference.

Python tries to make the expression/statement divide as clean as possible. But C++ tries to make everything that could possibly be an expression into an expression.

Going along with that, Python also tries to make the mutating/copying divide as clean as possible, by making mutating functions not return anything.

So, the right thing to do is what you're already doing:

```
thread.start_new_thread(isprime,(i,))
i += 1
```

The official Design FAQ covers some of this in [Why can't I use an assignment in an expression?](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/design.html#why-can-t-i-use-an-assignment-in-an-expression) and [Why doesn't list.sort() return the sorted list](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/design.html#why-doesn-t-list-sort-return-the-sorted-list), but they don't have too much depth.

Comment: Thanks, It's just somehow it was getting into an infinite loop of about 2 thousand and I thought that it was a result of the thread being called multiple times before incrementing.

Comment: @Hovestar: Well, there are a lot of problems with this code. You've got a ton of threads fighting over the same global variable without any synchronization. And you're not doing anything to wait until all the threads are finished. (While we're at it, why are you using `thread`? The first two paragraphs of the `thread` docs both tell you that you probably want `threading` instead.) But `i+=2` somehow not happening before the next loop iteration is _not_ your problem.